# wordpress js and css are served from IP address instead of domain name

Tags: wordpress, apache, lets-encrypt

I have installed SSL for my wordpress site (apache , ubuntu), in address bar the site is working with domain name, but JS and CSS file paths are showing as IP address instead of URL.

I have checked wp-config file  WordPress Address (URL) ,Site Address (URL)  is added correctly.

Help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have the WordPress address set to the IP address still.

To change this go to wp-admin and then Settings->General.

Change "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address(URL)" to the URL for your domain instead of the IP address.

Comment: @Navin Have you tried changing the URL in the database directly? I remember one WP site that I managed where I had to do that because WP wasn't applying URL settings correctly. You will need to access the wordpress table in your database, whatever its called. You can look in wp-config.php if you're not sure what DB name is. Then access the 'wp_options' table in the DB and change 'home' and 'url' options to your URL. Hope this works.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, it solved the issue. Even I update in config it is not updated in DB. Please post this as answer, I will accept the answer.